# Ajax to php internal session vars verification

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I am building a site and a page in it sends an ajax request to my php code and it change something in the database, I wanted to make sure that the request will be received only if the user is logged in using session vars but it doesn't prevent him from sending the request over and over again, what can I write that will prevent it?,

Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: check session in your php function, if its logged in then run the code else return,

Comment: Ya, I know, but what that I'm asking is if its logged then how can I prevent the user to submit unlimited number of ajax request and change the db in an unwanted way

Comment: Let's say that the site asks you a puzzle and you want to know the answer then you look in the code and you see the ajax request that submits your solution but instead of the one time that the site limits you to send it you are submitting it in your own machine multiple times until you get the answer

Comment: and because the user is logged the session will accept your submission (is it?)

Comment: no, if you have check, then it wont update db until its logged in. when you go on some site, they check if the user has a session already or not, if not they ask you for login or consider you a visitor unless you do some action that requires login, which then creates a session,

Comment: Either you can create an ajax that runs at some frequency and check user login/session status,  and in js you can set a global variable as true false, if the ajax replied that user is logged in mark true, else false, and can use the check on other ajax function

Comment: would be nice if you share some code, your ajax, and php